# Apache POI - Reading excel file in 2D array - returning null values

Tags: java, selenium, apache-poi

I am trying to read Excel -2*2 matrix through Apache POI. But the first value returned by 2D array is [null,null]. Please check my code and advise for suitable corrections.

```
public String[][] getDataArray(String sheetName)
{

    String value ="";
    String[][] data = null;


    int rowCount = wb.getSheet(sheetName).getLastRowNum();
    int colCount = wb.getSheet(sheetName).getRow(1).getLastCellNum()-1;

    data = new String[rowCount][colCount];

    for(int i=1; i<=rowCount;i++)
    {           

        Row row = wb.getSheet(sheetName).getRow(i);
        for(int j=0;j<colCount;j++)
        {


            Cell cell = row.getCell(j);
            if(cell.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)
            {
                value = ""+cell.getStringCellValue();
            }
            else
            {
                value = cell.getStringCellValue();
            }
            data[i][j] = value;


        }
    }
    return data;

}
```

The debug view where we can see that the first value stored in the variable data is null, null

The excel which i am trying to read. I need only the userName and password data(2*2) alone. Not the header and Run mode datas.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Of course the value in the index `0` will be null because the `i` starts from `1` and not `0`

```
for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++) //i starts from one
...
data[i][j] = value;
```

either initialize the `i` from 0 or do like this

```
data[i-1][j] = value;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static String[][] getSheetData(final String fileName, final String workSheetName)
            throws Exception {
        Integer lastRow = null;
        short lastCol = 0;
        String[][] sheetData = null;
        FileInputStream file=new FileInputStream(MettlTest.class.getClass().getResource("/" + fileName).getPath());
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        sheet = workbook.getSheet(workSheetName);
        try {
            XSSFRow row;
            XSSFCell cell;
            lastRow = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
            lastCol = sheet.getRow(1).getLastCellNum();
            sheetData = new String[lastRow - 1][lastCol];
            for (int r = 1; r < lastRow; r++) {
                row = sheet.getRow(r);
                if (row != null) {
                    for (int c = 0; c < lastCol; c++) {
                        cell = row.getCell(c);
                        if (cell == null) {
                            sheetData[r][c] = null;
                        } else {
                            sheetData[r-1][c] = new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(cell);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return sheetData;
        } 

        catch (final Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
        finally {
            try {
                file.close();
            } catch (IOException io) {
                Reporter.log("Unable to close File : " + fileName);
                throw io;
            }
        }
```